# WPF detect ASCII prefix of barcode scanner in previewKeyDown

Tags: c#, wpf, input, io, ascii

I have a 2D Barcode Scanner configured as an HID input device (acts as a normal keyboard).
My plan was to differentiate between user keyboard input and barcode-scanner input by looking for the prefix and suffix that the barcode scanner can add to the scanned characters.

I have currently configured the barcode scanner to use ASCII 0x02 (Start of Text) as the prefix and 0x03 (End of Text) as the suffix.

How can I detect these special ASCII inputs in C#?
I am using an KeyEventHandler to detect key inputs on PreviewKeyDown as well as PreviewKeyUp.

I've tried:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    this.PreviewKeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(PreviewKeyDownEventBarcodeScanner);
    this.PreviewKeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(PreviewKeyUpEventBarcodeScanner);
}

private void PreviewKeyDownEventBarcodeScanner(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    int vkey = (int)KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey(e.Key);
    stringOfVKeyInputs += vkey.ToString() + " ";
    stringOfKeyToTextInputs += e.Key.ToString();
}
```

Unfortunately none of the 2 variants (saved in the 2 strings) really helped to detect the special inputs.

- e.Key.ToString() always just outputs "System" for the 0x02 or 0x03 inputs.
- KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey(e.Key) gives 0x00 0x00 as an output for an ASCII 0x02 input; and 0x00 0x00 0xD as an output for an ASCII 0x03 input (which is bad because 0xD is VKEY_RETURN).

Is there any way to get the actual ASCII code of the input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you receive `Key.System`, check `e.SystemKey`

```csharp
int vkey = KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey(e.Key == Key.System ? e.SystemKey : e.Key);
```

Comment: Hey, that did actually help! I still think that it is strange that one cannot get the ASCII code directly, but with your solution the result is usable. :)) Thanks :)
With your line of code I'm now have the result string "0xA4 0x62 ACTUAL DATA 0xA4 0x63". With 0xA4 being LEFT_MENU_KEY and 0x62 and 0x63 representing 2 and 3 it is definitely readable as ASCII 0x02 and 0x03 :))
And I also got rid of the 0xD (Return) I had in there in the beginning (which was really annoying). It turned out that it was not bc of the special ASCII code, but actually sent by my barcode scanner :D Thank you

Comment: i was trying to do something else ,my scanners provoke `Shift+D1+Shift+D2` .. etc , and i wanted to detect if this pattern is being written , what should i use ?

Comment: @SUB-HDR looks like you need Keyboard Layout mapping but I'm not friendly with.